# Oracle - How to get nested data for XML

Tags: php, xml, oracle12c, nested-table

Is there a way to get (in one step or more) a nested set of data from `Oracle`?

In other words, my point is to obtain one or more cell that are `Arrays` instead of `Atomic Data`

**Example:**

```
    $result[0]["idJugadorId"] = "1";
    $result[0]["idOperadorId"] = "1";
    $result[0]["idCoorganizacion"] = "S";

    $result[0]["numeroDocumento"] = "11234";
    $result[0]["primerNombre"] = "Mario1";
    $result[0]["segundoNombre"] = "Giordano2";
    $result[0]["primerApellido"] = "Rossi1";
    $result[0]["segundoApellido"] = "Bianchi2";
    $result[0]["departamento"] = "5";
    $result[0]["ciudad"] = "5001";

    $result[0]["saldoInicialTotal"] = "1.000,00";
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseParticipacionTotal"] = "2.000,00";
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseParticipacionDesglose"][0]["OperadorId"] = "op1";
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseParticipacionDesglose"][0]["Importe"] = "1,00";      
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseParticipacionDesglose"][1]["OperadorId"] = "op1";
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseParticipacionDesglose"][1]["Importe"] = "1,00";  
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseParticipacionDesglose"][2]["OperadorId"] = "op1";
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseParticipacionDesglose"][2]["Importe"] = "1,00";  
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseBonoTotal"] = "3.000,00";
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseBonoDesglose"][0]["OperadorId"] = "op2";
    $result[0]["saldoInicialDegloseBonoDesglose"][0]["Importe"] = "2,00";
```

I'd like to know it, because I have to write this data in nested `XML` file.

**Example:**

```html
<ns1:SegundoApellido>Bianchi2</ns1:SegundoApellido>
   <ns1:Departamento>5</ns1:Departamento>
   <ns1:Ciudad>5001</ns1:Ciudad>
   <ns1:SaldoInicial>
    <ns1:Total>1.000,00</ns1:Total>
    <ns1:Desglose>
     <ns1:ImporteCreditoParticipacion>
      <ns1:Total>2.000,00</ns1:Total>
      <ns1:Desglose>
       <ns1:OperadorId>op1</ns1:OperadorId>
       <ns1:Importe>1,00</ns1:Importe>
      </ns1:Desglose>
      <ns1:Desglose>
       <ns1:OperadorId>op1</ns1:OperadorId>
       <ns1:Importe>1,00</ns1:Importe>
      </ns1:Desglose>
      <ns1:Desglose>
       <ns1:OperadorId>op1</ns1:OperadorId>
       <ns1:Importe>1,00</ns1:Importe>
      </ns1:Desglose>
     </ns1:ImporteCreditoParticipacion>
     <ns1:ImporteCreditoBono>
      <ns1:Total>3.000,00</ns1:Total>
      <ns1:Desglose>
       <ns1:OperadorId>op2</ns1:OperadorId>
       <ns1:Importe>2,00</ns1:Importe>
      </ns1:Desglose>
     </ns1:ImporteCreditoBono>
    </ns1:Desglose>
   </ns1:SaldoInicial>
```

Comment: Please show the existing SQL query

Comment: I have no sql query at the moment. We used an example set of data, putting values in the result array manually. 
Also the rest of the code is based on this structure of the result array, so we'd like to know if there is a way to retrieve data in the same way or we have to modify it